# How to modify state in a task (as commands do)?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a task within which I'd like to modify the state such that the next time it's called the property will be set. I know this is fairly easy with a `Command` but I want to know how to do it in a `Task`.

```scala
val myKey = AttributeKey[String]("my-key")

val getAttr = TaskKey[Unit]("get-attr")

val getAttrTask = getAttr <<= (state) map { (st) => 
  println(st.get(myKey))
  val newState = st.put(myKey, "hi")
  //How do I use the newState for the subsequent call?
}
```

Prints:

```
> get-attr //=> None 
> get-attr //=> Some("hi")
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to use task to change the state? AFAIK, tasks cannot change the build state. Only commands can do that.

Comment: The task in question sits into a dependency flow, if I turn it into a `Command` I'll have to make a whole bunch of other changes. I thought `Command` was the building block for a `Task`, so would have thought that there would be a way to interact with the `Command` context in some way in the `Task` context.

Comment: Tasks cannot modify state outside of what they implicitly change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** It's not possible to change `State` inside a task. Use commands.